# Java error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Optional<T> conforms to Iterable<AvailableLicence>

Tags: java, generics

Normally I'm a C# developer, but I'm trying to write some code in Java (first time in years) that uses generics to create a 'Retry' method that allows me to use a lambda expression to retry any block of code, basically. Here is my retry method:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> runWithRetry(final Supplier<T> t, int retryAttempts, long retryDelayInMilliseconds) throws InterruptedException {

        for(int retry = retryAttempts; retry >= 0; retry--) {
            try{
                return Optional.of(t.get());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                if(retry == 0) {
                    throw e;
                } else if (retryDelayInMilliseconds > 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(retryDelayInMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

And I'm attempting to call this method like so:

```
Iterable<AvailableLicence> licences = Helpers.runWithRetry(() -> {
            return licensor.findAvailableLicences(licenseOptions);
        }, 3, 5000);
```

but the Java compiler is throwing this error:

```
error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Optional<T> conforms to Iterable<AvailableLicence>
                Iterable<AvailableLicence> licences = Helpers.runWithRetry(() -> {
                                                                          ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>runWithRetry(Supplier<T>,int,long)
```

I think what this error is trying to tell me is that I am not specifying the type for `<T>` somewhere but I'm not entirely sure. I'm also combining some Java things like `Optional` and `Supplier` that I'm not sure if they could be causing the issue or not, despite having read up on how they work. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here? I feel like it's a simple syntax issue I'm missing here.

Comment: The `runWithRetry` method, I assume, returns an `Optional<Iterable<AvailableLicence>>` in this context but you're assigning it to a variable of type `Iterable<AvailableLicence>`.

Comment: What object does your `licensor.findAvailableLicences` return?

Comment: @NothingBox it returns an instance of Iterable<AvailableLicence>

Comment: @Slaw if I see what you mean. So if I change the way I'm calling the method to have it be returned into a variable of type `Optional<Iterable<AvailableLicence>>` and then use `.get()` to retrieve the `Iterable<AvailableLicence>` value out of it, that seems like it will work. However, that creates another compilation error related to handling exceptions within the lambda expression it seems: `error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                Optional<Iterable<AvailableLicence>> optLicences = Helpers.runWithRetry(() -> {`

Comment: It looks like I can remove the `Throws InterruptedException` part from the runWithRetry method signature, and just handle that `InterruptedException` in a try/catch within the `else if` that contains the `Thread.sleep()` call and then there's no need to deal with it outside in the lambda expression that's calling it.

Comment: So basically the try/catch becomes this:

`try{
    return Optional.of(t.get());
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
    if(retry == 0) {
     throw e;
    } else if (retryDelayInMilliseconds > 0) {
     try {
      Thread.sleep(retryDelayInMilliseconds);
     } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
      // just swallow it? maybe ie.printStackTrace();?
     }
    }
   }`

Comment: I wouldn't use `get()`, at least not without checking that the value is present first, since that method can throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the `Optional` is empty. In other words, you should do `if (optional.isPresent()) { / * get and use value */ }` or use `optional.ifPresent(value -> /* use value */)`. But yes, you need to actually unwrap the value or change the type of your variable to the desired type. Note this problem is not specific to generics but is simple "type safety"; you'd get a very similar error if you tried to do `int a = "a string"`.

Comment: As for handling the `InterruptedException` that depends on how you want the method to behave. Do you want the waits to be interruptible? If so, then continue having `runWithRetry` be capable of throwing the exception and handle it externally. If not, then simply swallowing the exception is not necessarily enough—check out [`Uinterruptibles#sleepUninterruptibly(long,TimeUnit)`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/android/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.java#L307) from _Guava_.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw your comments are helpful. I am looking at refactoring this now to make it a bit better.

Comment: Thanks @Guava your comments are helpful. I am looking at refactoring this now to make it a bit better.

Comment: Just to note: [_Guava_](https://github.com/google/guava) is an open-source library (maintained by Google). If you don't mind pulling in dependencies for what you want to accomplish you may also want to check out [_failsafe_](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe).

Comment: @Slaw good to know, thanks for the tip on that libary. May look into that in the future if my needs for that type of execution behavior grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would spare the caller of *`runWithRetry()`* having to handle the checked *`InterruptedException`*. [*For example like this*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/9t)…

```
public static <T> Optional<T> runWithRetry(final Supplier<T> t, int retryAttempts, long retryDelayInMilliseconds) {

    return handleSleep(t, retryAttempts, retryDelayInMilliseconds);
}
    
private static <T> Optional<T> handleSleep(final Supplier<T> t, int retryAttempts, long retryDelayInMilliseconds){ 
        
    Optional<T> retVal = Optional.empty();
        
    for(int retry = retryAttempts; retry >= 0; retry--) {
        try{
            retVal = Optional.of(t.get());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            if(retry == 0) {
                throw e;
            } else if (retryDelayInMilliseconds > 0) {
                  try{
                      Thread.sleep(retryDelayInMilliseconds);
                  } catch(InterruptedException ie){ /*TODO: Handle or log warning */ }
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

See how I used that [*in my demo*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/9t)…

```
...
Optional<Iterable<AvailableLicense>> licenses = Deduper.runWithRetry( ()-> 

    { return licensor.findAvailableLicenses(licenseOptions); }, 3, 5000 );
    
licenses.ifPresent(out::println);
...
```

Because I've implemented *`AvailableLicense.toString()`*, my demo outputs…

```
[AvailableLicense[ type: To Kill!]]
```

[*Optional - The Mother of all Bikesheds*](https://inside.java/2017/04/11/optional/) from @StuartMarks — one of the Oracle core devs that implemented *`Optional`* is recommended viewing for *everybody* using *`Optional`*.

Comment: Thanks much for this comment. This has cleared up some things for me and helped with some refactoring I'm doing now based on this. Nice demo too!

Comment: You're welcome jamauss. Glad it helped you. Can you help *future me* with something please? What would have needed to change about my answer, that would have improved the chances of you considering marking it as the accepted answer? Genuinely curious. TIA.

Comment: Thanks @deduper - I've chosen this as the accepted answer as I feel it helped me refactor the working code the most and helped my understanding of what I was doing.

Comment: Hey! Neat! Thank you @jamauss. — „*Nice demo too!*“ — Thanks again. I didn't know it at the time I shared that demo link, but I've since discovered that there is a bug in that online IDE I used. So if you saw the _`DeduperAnswer.java`_ main class launch as an empty file, I apologize. I've reported the bug to the owner. — P.S. — „*...refactor the working code...*“ — It would be a good learning experience for me to see a simple demo of your refactored working code. Maybe in [*Ideone*](https://ideone.com)?